# Casting between PostGIS types in GeoAlchemy

Tags: python, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, geoalchemy

I'm working with OpenStreetMap data, and loading it into a PostGIS database using osm2pgsql.

The issue that I am currently dealing with is that osm2pgsql stores the shape as a geometry type.

I'm using GeoAlchemy2 to query the Postgres database, but I am having issues with the following query.

```
query = session.query(Route).filter(func.ST_Distance(Route.way,'SRID=4326;POINT(10.71223 47.69716)') < distance )
```

Because osm2pgsql stores the data as a Geometry type, it doesn't interpret my points as a geography type, and therefore doesn't filter based on distance in meters, but rather in degrees.

Would there be a way to cast the Geometry type objects (Route.way and the string representation of the point ) to a Geography form?

Answer (score 2):

I realized that it is possible to cast from the Geometry object to the Geography object using the SQLAlchemy function, despite the two not being native SQLAlchemy objects.

```
query = session.query(Route).filter(func.ST_Distance(cast(Route.way,Geography),'SRID=4326;POINT(10.71223 47.69716)') < distance )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your route.way is already in WGS84, EPSG:4326, then casting should be possible.

I have not used GeoAlchemy2 but based on your syntax it should be:

```
query = session.query(Route).filter(func.ST_Distance(Route.way::geography,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(10.71223 47.69716)',4326)::geography) < distance
```

Comment: Sadly that is not valid syntax in python. (Oops, let me add that tag now)

Comment: You could store your data as geography in the database? Simply create a geography column and populate it using "route.way::geography" then you should be able to create your query points in geoalchamy using'ST_GeogFromText'. http://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.org/en/0.2.6/_modules/geoalchemy2/types.html?highlight=geography

Comment: That is a valid option that I failed to consider. It's a bit clunky to add the column in after importing the OSM data, but I'll work with it until I give up on searching for a solution on the side. Thanks!